# Check validation if date is < 3 months

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation, date

i want to get a validation from this case. If the entry date is less than now. So it would result an alert and redirect to the homepage. I wrote this one but it didn't work.

```
        $dateEntry = array($current_employee->emp_dtentry);

        if ($dateEntry < strtotime('+3 months')) {
            echo "<script>alert('you don't have the right to access this menu')</script>";
            redirect('new_leave','refresh');
        }
```

Will appreciate any help, thanks before!

Comment: It's going inside if condition?

Comment: Yes, am i doing something wrong? :(

Comment: What is the value of `$current_employee->emp_dtentry`?

Comment: You're initializing `$dateEntry` as an array, but not indexing it in your if statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are putting your date into an array and then comparing it to a timestamp. Why are you doing that?

Assuming `$current_employee->emp_dtentry` is a Unix timestamp:

```
if ($current_employee->emp_dtentry < strtotime('+3 months')) {
```

If it is not a Unix timestamp and is a [valid date format](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php) you can do:

```
if (strtotime($current_employee->emp_dtentry) < strtotime('+3 months')) {
```

If it is not a valid date format you would need to use [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) to parse the date and then do your comparison. That is easier to do with DateTime objects throughout.

```
// see manual format options
$empdtEntry = DateTime::createFromFormat('<format goes here>', ($current_employee->emp_dtentry); 
$current_employee->emp_dtentry);
$threeMonthsFromNow = new DateTime(+3 months);
if ($empdtEntry < $threeMonthsFromNow ) {
```

Answer (score 2):

As you are redirecting, your echo won't work. Either flash your javascript or use javascript there to redirect too.

Using flash:

```
 $dateEntry = $current_employee->emp_dtentry;
 if ($dateEntry < strtotime('+3 months')) {
    $this->session->set_flashdata("javascript", "<script>alert('you don't have the right to access this menu')</script>");
    redirect('new_leave');
 }
```

Then within the `new_leave` view check it if exists and echo it:

```
if($this->session->flashdata('javascript')){
    echo $this->session->flashdata('javascript');
}
```

Or using javascript do it as below:

```
 $dateEntry = $current_employee->emp_dtentry;
 if ($dateEntry < strtotime('+3 months')) {
    echo "<script>alert('you don't have the right to access this menu'); window.location.href='new_leave';</script>";
 }
```

Comment: Ah i see, so that's why it won't redirects. thanks for your info. I appreciate it!